# View does not have a NavController set when using Fragment Factory and Navigation Component

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I'm refactoring my app to use Fragment Factory. Everything was working fine with navigation components before the refactoring but now the fragments cannot find the Nav Controller anymore, error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: View androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout{7c24bdc V.E...... ......I. 0,0-1080,2088 #7f0a0061 app:id/auth_nav_host_fragment} does not have a NavController set
    at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.java:84)
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.findNavController(NavHostFragment.java:118)
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentKt.findNavController(Fragment.kt:29)
    at com.kalianey.oneness.ui.auth.LauncherFragment.navLogin(LauncherFragment.kt:42)
    at com.kalianey.oneness.ui.auth.LauncherFragment.access$navLogin(LauncherFragment.kt:16)
    at com.kalianey.oneness.ui.auth.LauncherFragment$onViewCreated$1.onClick(LauncherFragment.kt:28)
```

I created a fragment factory:

```
@AuthScope
class AuthFragmentFactory
@Inject
constructor(
private val viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
) : FragmentFactory() {

override fun instantiate(classLoader: ClassLoader, className: String) =

    when (className) {

        OnboardingPagerFragment::class.java.name -> {
            OnboardingPagerFragment()
        }

        OnboardingOneFragment::class.java.name -> {
            OnboardingOneFragment()
        }

        OnboardingTwoFragment::class.java.name -> {
            OnboardingTwoFragment()
        }

        OnboardingThreeFragment::class.java.name -> {
            OnboardingThreeFragment()
        }

        LauncherFragment::class.java.name -> {
            LauncherFragment(viewModelFactory)
        }

        LoginFragment::class.java.name -> {
            LoginFragment(viewModelFactory)
        }

        RegisterFragment::class.java.name -> {
            RegisterFragment(viewModelFactory)
        }

        ForgotPasswordFragment::class.java.name -> {
            ForgotPasswordFragment(viewModelFactory)
        }

        else -> {
            LauncherFragment(viewModelFactory)
        }
    }

 }
```

Provided like this in my module:

```
@JvmStatic
@AuthScope
@Provides
fun provideFragmentFactory(viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory, requestManager: RequestManager, sessionManager: SessionManager): FragmentFactory{
    return AuthFragmentFactory(viewModelFactory)
}
```

And I set it up like this in my AuthActivity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    inject()
    supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory = fragmentFactory
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_auth)
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set a `FragmentFactory`, it's responsible for instantiating *every* fragment `AuthActivity` might need.  However, when the system tries to instantiate `NavHostFragment`, your factory creates a `LauncherFragment` instead.  This means you never actually created a `NavHostFragment`, and you don't have a `NavController`.

Instead of creating a `LauncherFragment`, your `else` case should create whichever fragment class was requested.

```
else -> {
    super.instantiate(classLoader, className)
}
```